# Encoding windows-1255

Tags: apex, xml, encoding

I have created an apex class which created an xml using:

```
xmlW.writeStartDocument('windows-1255','1.0');
```

but I get the following error:

> Underlying stream encoding 'UTF-8' and input parameter for writeStartDocument() method 'windows-1255' do not match.

How can I create an XML with another encoding than UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not fixed in SF.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SjVQAA0

You can vote for the idea, but in the current moment you have nothing else to do, than leave UTF-8 encoding.